# Loading additional parameters to scipy's rv_continuous

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability, probability-density

I am planning to do some basic algebra on continuous, non-analytical random variabels. I want to define their probability density functions as arrays x and f(x).

Yet, I was surprised to find out that there does not seem to be any package that does basic operations like computing sum- or product distributions of two pdfs (please correct me if I'm wrong). To implement those operations by myself, I then planned to create a subclass of scipy.stats rv_continuous, following [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/define-custom-probability-density-function-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

class my_pdf(sp.stats.rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self,x,p):
        self.x = x
        self.p = p

    def _pdf(self,x):
        return sp.interpolate.interp1d(self.x,self.p)(x)

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
f = 3*x**2
my_cv = my_pdf(x,f)
my_cv.pdf(0)
```

The last line throws an error, because overwriting the init method is probably not the way to go. Is there a way to pass additional parameters to rv_continuous, or another way to approach the problem, other than building everything from scratch?

Comment: Two comments: (1) You will want to call the super constructor in your overwritten `__init__` like that: `super().__init__()`. (2) Your example is probably not perfect, because the integral over the support has to sum to 1 to be a valid distribution from a statistical point of view :-)

Comment: (1) could you please elaborate that? As I understand `super()`, it would call the `__init__` method of the superclass, `rv_continuous` in this case. My problem is, however, that `rv_continuous` does not take the additional parameters I need to pass.
(2) if I integrate `3*x**2` from 0 to 1, I get 1 :)

Comment: I posted a snippet which I think might work. Sorry, I screwed (2) up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

class my_pdf(sp.stats.rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self,x,p):
        super().__init__(a=x.min(), b=x.max())
        self.x = x
        self.p = p
    
    def _pdf(self,x):
        return sp.interpolate.interp1d(self.x,self.p)(x)

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
f = 3*x**2
my_cv = my_pdf(x,f)
my_cv.pdf(0)
my_cv.cdf(0.5)
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you! you can get rid of that range-check and increase efficiency by passing the limits of the support: `super().__init__(a=x[0],b=x[-1])`. Maybe you want to add that, as I cannot edit your answer